# How to make Grafana's datasource plugin compliant with Query Inspector?

Tags: plugins, datasource, grafana

I'm developping a datasource plugin for Grafana that works nicely but if I try to use the *Query Inspector*, I only get the following message *"Loading query inspector... "*.

So how to make my plugin compliant with this feature? Is there any specific function to add to my datasource.ts file ?

[edit]
I'm using Grafana 6.7.1 and @grafana/toolkit

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I think I understood how it works.

The **query inspector** is triggered only if an event (`dsRequestResponse` or `dsRequestError`) is emitted after the query is done by the backend server (see [code documentation](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/a2d741f60fbe7ef3482ae8a9e44fe293db60fcea/packages/grafana-runtime/src/services/backendSrv.ts#L66))

For example :

```js
import { getBackendSrv } from '@grafana/runtime';

//later in your code
getBackendSrv().datasourceRequest({
      url:'https://api.github.com/repos/grafana/grafana/stats/commit_activity',
      method:'GET'
    }).then((data: any) => console.log('DATA',data));
```

In my  datasource, I'm doing `fetch()` call from the browser so no event is emitted and then no data are displayed in the **query inspector**. But here is a workaround to emit the event :

```js
import { SystemJS } from '@grafana/runtime'
//later in your code
SystemJS.load('app/core/app_events').then((appEvents:any) => {
    appEvents.emit('ds-request-response', data) // where data is the data to display
})
```

I hope it can help someone else